# Making an EOS delay send transaction into the future?

Tags: transactions, deferred-transactions

Is it possible to send a delayed transaction using EOS? Say I want to send 5 EOS to someone after 24 hours has passed. How can one do this in EOS? Do I need a smart contract? And does my EOS get locked for that time frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use **cleos** to do the delay send by adding the option:

```
--delay-sec [seconds to delay]
```

And no it does not lock up your eos, it will just fail when that time comes to send it.

Comment: Can you please whole command for sending eos with delayed time for future reference?